# Rust static function fn pointer, which value to initialize?

Tags: c, rust

I'm trying to create a Rust library callable from C:

```rust
use std::os::raw::{c_int};

type OnDataCallback = unsafe extern "C" fn(data: *mut u8, len: usize) -> c_int;

static mut onDataCallback_: OnDataCallback = std::ptr::null();

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn registerOnDataCallback(
    data: *const u8, len: usize,
    cb: Option<OnDataCallback>) -> c_int
{
    onDataCallback_ = cb.unwrap();
    return 0;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn doSomething()
{
    unsafe{onDataCallback_(mut "hello world" , 100)};
}
```

But I'm getting:

```rust
--> interface.rs:5:46
  |
5 | static mut onDataCallback_: OnDataCallback = std::ptr::null();
  |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found *-ptr
  |
  = note: expected fn pointer `unsafe extern "C" fn(*mut u8, usize) -> i32`
            found raw pointer `*const _`
```

I don't have idea on what to put there for the initial value. I can't let it without one, and I can't put null. What should I put?

PS: if what I'm doing is a bad practice, please show me a good one. I'm new at Rust.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that. Maybe something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=127e070459a1fef1adb1ef7a95c9167f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it with a function that panics:

```rust
static mut ON_DATA_CALLBACK: OnDataCallback = init;

extern "C" fn init(_: *mut u8, _: usize) -> c_int {
    panic!("Function pointer not initialized");
}
```

Be aware that `static mut` is *wildly* unsafe, and its use is generally discouraged, because it's so difficult use it correctly. A safe alternative is to use a <s>`RefCell`</s> `Mutex` in a `static`. Since `Mutex` has interior mutability, the `static` doesn't need to be mutable.

A better solution would be to use [once_cell](https://lib.rs/crates/once_cell) or [lazy_static](https://lib.rs/crates/lazy_static) to initialize the function the first time `doSomething()` is called.

By the way, Rust string literals are always *immutable*. You can get a mutable string by allocating a `String`. See [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=615803f936cbe7760ac49fcd9ea1b213).

Answer (score 5):

You should wrap it in an `Option` and initialize it with `None`.

```
static mut onDataCallback_: Option<OnDataCallback> = None;
```

Comment: thanks. Is it the best way to do it though? I had to put unsafe: `unsafe{onDataCallback_ = cb;}` otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: `static mut` is almost never the best way. `Cell` wrapped in `thread_local!` or `Mutex` wrapped in `lazy_static` (depending on whether do you need thread-safety or not) is almost always better.